# best way to find substring in ruby using regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex, string, url, substring

I have a string `https://stackverflow.com`. I want a new string that contains the domain from the given string using regular expressions.

Example:

```
x = "https://stackverflow.com"
newstring = "stackoverflow.com"
```

Example 2:

```
x = "https://www.stackverflow.com"
newstring = "www.stackoverflow.com"
```

Comment: Isn't `"http://stackoverflow.com".split("://").last` enough?

Comment: It's nice to show at least a bit of commitment in solving the issue and then ask where you are stuck.

Comment: "Please give me" is not the way SO works. Or maybe it does, since you got 4 answers.

Comment: While many don't like "give me code" questions much, that's not a valid close reason.  This question is neither too broad nor unclear.  A downvote might be appropriate here, but closing is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `string = "http://stackoverflow.com"`,

a really easy way is `string.split("http://")[1]`. But this isn't regex.

A regex solution would be as follows:

```
string.scan(/^http:\/\/(.+)$/).flatten.first
```

To explain:

1. `String#scan` returns the first match of the regex.
2. The regex:

   - `^` matches beginning of line
   - `http:` matches those characters
   - `\/\/` matches `//`
   - `(.+)` sets a "match group" containing any number of any characters. This is the value returned by the scan.
   - `$` matches end of line
3. `.flatten.first` extracts the results from `String#scan`, which in this case returns a nested array.

Comment: I do not think you need a `.scan` if you need to only get one occurrence. `string[/\Ahttps?:\/\/(.+)\z/, 1]` is enough.

Comment: Please note that the first example provided by OP has `https`.

Comment: Point taken - mine is not the most concise regex. If you could explain your solutions piece-by-piece, though, it'd be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

```
"https://stackverflow.com"[/(?<=:\/\/).*/]
#⇒ "stackverflow.com"
```

`(?<=..)` is a [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: My pet peeve: if you can do without an unanchored lookbehind, you should consider it. I'd go with `"https://stackverflow.com"[/:\/\/(.*)/, 1]`. Unanchored lookarounds are costly in terms of performance (in general).  I understand these strings must be short, but it is a matter of best practices.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew In the particular case of regexping domain name that makes not much sense and I vote for readability over premature optimization :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

str = "https://stackoverflow.com"

if mtch = str.match(/(?::\/\/)(/S)/)
  f1 = mtch.captures
end
```

There are two capturing groups in the `match` method: the first one is a non-capturing group referring to your search pattern and the second one referring to everything else afterwards. After that, the `captures` method will assign the desired result to `f1`.

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Use anonymous group to not capture: `(/(?::\/\/)(/S)/`. `i` modifier makes no sense on that regexp.